# advice with my javascript collision detection

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm attempting to make a top-down shooter style game reminiscent of the old Galaga games.
I've got the player and enemies and projectiles moving and working fine apart from when I try to check for collisions between the bullets being fired by the player and the enemy spaceships.

both the bullets and enemies are made using constructors and then placed in an array to keep track of them.

```
//due to the number of enemies on screen they'll be held in an array
var enemies = [];
    for(e = 0; e < enemies; e++) {
        enemies[e] = [];
        enemies[e] = {x:0,y:0};
}

//class constructor to create enemies
class enemy {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.enemyX = x;
        this.enemyY = y;
        this.enemyWidth = 32;
        this.enemyHeight = 32;
    }
}

//variable array for the bullets
var playerBullets = [];
    for(i = 0; i < playerBullets; i++) {
    playerBullets[i] = { x: 0, y: 0 };
}

//class constructor to create the bullets
class bullet {
    constructor(x,y){
        this.bulletX = x;
        this.bulletY = y;
        this.bulletWidth = 5;
        this.bulletHeight = 5;
    }
}
```

I have tried to make a collision detector function that first goes through the array of bullets and then the array of enemies and checks for overlapping borders and to give an alert when a collision has been found, but I'm having trouble with it. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

```
//code for detecting collisions from the bullets
function collisionDetection() {
    for(i = 0; i < playerBullets.length; i++) {
        for(e = 0; e < enemies.length; e++) {   
            if (playerBullets[i].x < enemies.x + enemy.width  && 
playerBullets[i].x + bullet.width  > enemies.x &&
            playerBullets[i].y < enemies.y + enemy.height && 
playerBullets[i].y + bullet.height > enemies.y){
                alert("HIT");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Peter when the code is in a working state then it can be posted there. But until then, the OP typed "_I'm having trouble with it._" and thus it would be [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: sorry my bad, if bullets and enemies are both circle shape, you just need to calculate the mid point distance with Pythagorean theorem, and if C is smaller then the 2 circle radios it is a hit.

Comment: No both the bullets and enemies are square shaped, at the moment I'm pretty sure it's the "if" statement that's wrong but for the life of me I can't figure out how

Comment: @Dodge if x y coordinates is the middle point of the enemies / bullets, you need to divide height and width by 2

Comment: @Dodge I checked your code closer see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed the index of the enemies: `enemies[e]` and enemy has `enemyX` `enemyY` `enemyWidth` and `enemyHeight` property,  and `bullets` has: `bulletX`, `bulletY` `bulletWidth` `bulletHeight`

```
function collisionDetection() {
    for(i = 0; i < playerBullets.length; i++) {
        for(e = 0; e < enemies.length; e++) {   
            if (playerBullets[i].bulletX < enemies[e].enemyX + enemies[e].enemyWidth && 
playerBullets[i].bulletX + playerBullets[i].bulletWidth > enemies[e].enemyX &&
            playerBullets[i].bulletY < enemies[e].enemyY + enemies[e].enemyHeight && 
playerBullets[i].bulletY + playerBullets[i].bulletHeight > enemies[e].enemyY){
                alert("HIT");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```